# Delphi tethering ResourceReceived fails to update TLabel

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Delphi 10.2.3 FMX app tethering

Sometimes the label in the following code gets updated but often it does not. Is it not safe to update a visual component during the tethering RescourceReceived procedure?

```
procedure TMainForm.MyTetheringAppProfileResourceReceived(
  const Sender: TObject; const AResource: TRemoteResource);

begin
  if AResource.Hint = 'InfoPrincipleVariation'
    then
      begin

        MyInformationLabel.Text := AResource.Value.AsString;  // Fails to update
        Exit;
      end;
end;
```

I got around the problem by storing the value in AResource.Value.AsString and then enabling a timer that later set the value of the label's text.

Comment: This is completely wrong duplicate. It is not about whether you can update UI from background thread but why updating UI does not work from tethering event. Since Delphi events commonly operate on main thread, this is somewhat unexpected behavior.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar:  Fair enough, I've voted to re-open this q as I wasn't intending to stifle answers.  But looking at the source of `TTetheringAppProfile.DoResourceReceived` it looked to me like it is capable of being called from another thread, depending on the value of `SynchronizeEvents`.  Iyswim ...

Comment: @MartynA Thanks. Yes, it is capable of being called from another thread, but it is somewhat unexpected for Delphi that drag and drop component has events that are not running in main thread context. Actually, back in the day when AppTethering was introduced it didn't had SynchronizeEvents property at all, but it was added after people were commonly  baffled why it works so flaky :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Commonly Delphi events are triggered within main thread (UI controls) or are synchronized with main thread (`TThread.OnTernimate` - event). However that is not always the case.

Tethering operates from background thread and its event are also called from background thread. On the other hand, all UI access must be synchronized with main UI thread.

`TTetheringProfile` class (ancestor of `TTetheringAppProfile`) has `SynchronizeEvents` property (by default set to `True`) that controls on which thread are events called. If `True` all event handlers will run in context of main thread.

Symptoms you are having are consistent with accessing UI from the secondary thread. Check the value of `SynchronizeEvents` property or synchronize UI access with main thread within your event handler.

Comment: The `SynchronizeEvents` property is set to True, the default setting, for both the tethering manager and the tethering profile component. Still, I agree that the behavior is consistent with UI controls being accessed from a background thread which I didn't expect.